# package.json custom scripts not being executed

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

`NPM 8.1.2`
`Node.js 16.13.1`

(installed both from the lts executable from https://nodejs.org/en/)

I wanna use the custom scripts to start my angular application.

```
{
  "name": "TestApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve --port 4201",
  }
}
```

If I type `npm start` I get the following output:

[image: instead of starting application it return back to prompt]

Instead of starting the application after executing the command it turns back to the prompt.

But if I execute the command which is in the custom script directly into the prompt the application starts.

[image: starting application when executing ng command directly]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Dou you have any dependencies? Looks like a scoping issue to me. May you try to install angular directly into your project?

Comment: yes some angular dependencies. I shortend the whole package.json to the minimum

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is running `npm config get ignore-scripts` in your termenal.  If it returns `true` run `npm config set ignore-scripts false` .  That might help.

Comment: sorry, that didn't help at all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).